# Distance between 2 incenters

Tags: triangles

Let $\triangle{ABC}$ have side lengths $\overline{AB}=3$, $\overline{BC}=5$, $\overline{CA}=7$ and let $D$ be the circumcenter of this triangle. Also, let $E$ be the incenter of $\triangle{ABD}$. $F$ is the incenter of $\triangle{ACD}$. Find the length of segment $\overline{EF}$.

This problem is begging for a diagram, but herein lies the problem. It is difficult to construct a $3-5-7$ triangle. Even more difficult to find the circumcenter and incenter of these triangles. Help is much appreciated and needed.

Comment: The question asks for the distance between two incenters, but the title asks for the distance between a circumcenter and an incenter, is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

If this is the main problem then here is how to construct a 3-5-7 triangle. Assume that the radius of the little white circles is one. Then

[image]

Comment: Now what should I do?